# SQL query where it sorts by Release Date first, then Episode, Then part

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to do this query where all the newest entries (episodes) are at the top (first). BUT, if two episodes are uploaded on the same day it sorts by episode number (keeping the date order from before but sorting only within each day by episode) then if there are multiple parts to an episode, sorting within each episode by part as well.

```
. "ORDER BY `part`,`episode`,`release_date` DESC";
```

i've tried this order by search as well as

```
. "ORDER BY `release_date`,`part`,`episode` DESC";
```

but both of these result in episode 1 being at the top, but I want the most recent episode to be at that top (so the higher number episode)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `release_date`, it should be first sorted by `episode` and then `part`

```
"ORDER BY `release_date`,`episode`,`part` DESC";
```

There is also an option of ASC/DESC per column, if required.

```
"ORDER BY `release_date` DESC,`episode` DESC,`part` ASC";
```

Comment: The second one is exactly what I needed. Had to isolate the direction of order. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. Please do accept the answer if it suffice your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it sounds like you want to sort by:

1. release_date (descending order, i.e. newest first)
2. episode (descending order, also newest first)
3. part (ascending order, part 1, 2, 3, etc)

so the order by would be

```
. "ORDER BY `release_date` DESC, `episode` DESC, `part` ASC";
```